# Windows Embedded Compact 2013: missing function in SDK

Tags: c++, sdk, windows-embedded-compact

I am working with making a minshell in c++ for our BSP, we wanted it in native for speed and stability (feel free to coment on this). Anyways, we have made our own SDK (to work with ARM processors) and I think maybe the problem itself explains my confusion:

The function SetMenu does not get recognized by our SDK, but for AppendMenu (same .dll, same header) there are no problems, and a lot of other API works aswell. When i change the SDK to x64 the function is recognized. Anyone know What's going on? Or does someone know of a way to isolate the problem at least?

Excuse me if this is too vague.
Thanks

Comment: Minimal code sample, error messages? This is indeed too vague.

Comment: @MSalters
Yea, sorry:

error C3861: 'SetMenu': identifier not found 

is the error msg, the code is a simple call, nothing wrong there, as mentioned the errormsg goes away / the call is recognized when i change SDK to the x64 frame. Not very helpful, i know..